# multiple option echo php & mysql

Tags: php, html

how can i output more when 1 array. when i delete , ["nr"] evrything works. but i need the second one too...

```
<div>
      <select name="name[]">
           <option value = ""> Select the person with phone nbr. </option>
           <?php foreach ($results as $output) {?>

           <option> <?php echo $output ["fname"],["nr"]; ?> </option>

      <?php } ?>
      </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is the expected HTML output? Also, this seems prone to XSS.

Comment: <option value="SOME_VALUE"> <?php echo $output ["fname"].",".["nr"]; ?> </option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does "nr" is an index of $output array? if so, then you have to write it like this:

```
<?php echo $output["fname"]  . "," . $output["nr"]; ?>
```

Comment: @whoamiidontknowit can you please accept the answer as solution? :)